# Failed navigation test with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, react-bootstrap

In my code I use react-router-dom with react-boostrap elements. I've been trying to do some navigation tests. I have no experience in unit testing so every tip will be appreciated.

My Routes are in seperate file:

```
function Routes() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Container>
                        <Row className="mt-3">
                            <Deck />
                        </Row>
                        <Row className="mt-3">
                            <Deck />
                        </Row>
                    </Container>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/about">
                    <h1>About_us</h1>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/dashboard">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/faq">
                    <h1>FAQ</h1>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/login">
                    <LoginPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/signup">
                    <SignUpPage />
                </Route>
                <Route>
                    <h1>Bad page</h1>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

The unit test portion:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Routes from '../src/Routes.js';


test('full app navigating', async () => {

    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
            <Routes />
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getAllByText(/Card info/i)[0]).toBeInTheDocument();


    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Flashcards/i));
    let result = await screen.findAllByText(/Card info/i);
    expect(result[0]).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Home/i));
    result = await screen.findAllByText(/Card info/i);
    expect(result[0]).toBeInTheDocument();


    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/About/i));
    result = await screen.findByText(/About_us/i);
});
```

So on the path "/" I'm displaying Deck component which basically has "Card info" text in it. That's why I  search for that text. On the other hand path "/about" just renders `<h1>About_us</h1>`. App works fine when i run it but testing with jest results in error:

```
FAIL  tests/Routes.test.js
  × full app navigating (1123 ms)

  ● full app navigating

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /About_us/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

It seems I do not navigate properly in my unit test.

EDIT: When I change initialEntries to "/about" the app renders stuff at that route so path works by itself. It must be related to that line:

```
fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/About/i));
```

About is just a <Nav.Link> bootstrap tag with href="/about" so that's how I redirect to /about .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for everyone struggling: The problem was <Nav.Link href="/about">About_us</Nav.Link>. It was quite confusing because in fact I have both frontend-side routing via React Router and backend-side side via Express (basically every GET request gets passed to index.html where react handles what to display). The solution was to use:

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">About_us</Nav.Link>
```

So the whole tag behaves as a React Router element and in test environment it properly navigates to /about.